# Cronjobs Reporting Negative Execution Times?

Tags: cron, timezone

I'm getting a fairly weird result trying to check the status of my Magento store's cron jobs.

I tried installing both AOE Scheduler and Noovias Cronjob Manager.  Both of them give me something like this:

"Scheduler is working. (Last execution: -239 minute(s) ago)"

My only guess is that it last ran *1* minute ago - I am in Eastern time, which due to Daylight Saving Time is UTC-4.  240 minutes would be 4 hours.  However, both my PHP configuration and MySQL database specify "America/New_York" as the timezone.  Why are the times showing in the negative?

And if I am correct in thinking it's just a time offset, is this fixable?

Comment: What is the timezone configured in Magento? Does that also match the America/New York timezone?

Comment: Yes: In the admin panel, it does show Estern (America/New York) under System->Configuration->General->Locale Options->Timezone